# How do I connect to Hadoop using SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, ssms

Trying to view all the databases listed in HIVE (Hadoop) within SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set up the Hadoop cluster as a "linked server". This should help: https://runops.wordpress.com/2015/10/17/create-sql-server-linked-server-to-hadoop/